# Server created in JS but it runs my index.html incorrectly

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I created this drawing app, in which a user can draw when the mouse is down and there's a clear button to clear the canvas. I used Javascript and HTML for the code. It works perfectly when I run it as an HTML file. Below is a screenshot:

[My drawing app when opened via my "index.html" file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72a0V.png)

For our class, we are tasked with converting our app into an executable. So I thought of adding some http server code so that the user can go to a localhost url and run the app. However, this is the screenshot I get when I run "node index.js" which contains the server code:

[As you can see, it's different. Plus, I don't get the ability to draw when my mouse is down.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q6Ozr.png)

Also, here is my code:

**index.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css" />
    <title>ogre</title>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="button" style="text-align: center;">
        <input type="button" style="font-size: 25px; width:100px; height:40px" id="clear" value="clear">
    </div>
    <script>
        document.getElementById('clear').addEventListener('click', function(){
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            const context = canvas.getContext("2d");
            context.clearRect(0,0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
        }, false);
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="canvas.js"></script>
</body>
```

**index.js**

```
var http = require('http');
var fs = require('fs');

const PORT=8080; 

fs.readFile('./index.html', function (err, html) {

  if (err) throw err;    

  http.createServer(function(request, response) {  
    response.writeHeader(200, {"Content-Type": "text/html"});  
    response.write(html);  
    response.end();  
  }).listen(PORT);
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "executable",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "Simple express app",
    "main": "index.js",
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node index.js",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "",
    "license": "ISC",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "^4.17.1"
    }
}
```

I didn't add my `canvas.js` file because I believe it is running correctly as I had tested it before. I think the main issues are in my "index.html" and "index.js" files. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I forgot to mention, basically what I think is happening, is that my "index.html" file isn't running my "canvas.js" file properly, hence me not being able to draw but the "clear" button showing up. However, I have no idea why that's happening when there's an http server involved...

Comment: Probably has to do with the `href="./style.css"` or the `src="canvas.js"`. Check your network log and make sure the requests are going through.

Comment: if you are tasked to convert it to an executable then I don't think making it run on a server is want they wanted. From the word executable or exe is a windows desktop application format so I think you should use a frame work like Electron js to make an executable file. Its really easy to do

Comment: You need to set a "public" directory.

Comment: https://github.com/windowjs/windowjs might be helpful

Comment: Your server is not serving canvas.js only index.html. I also would not create a server in the callback to `fs.readFile`. Are you even going to use `express`? If so check out https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html. Otherwise you have to write server code to inspect the `request` and serve the right asset.

Comment: You'd learn more if you did it without `express`: https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/HTTP/servers/how-to-serve-static-files/

Comment: @seriously Thanks for the comment! Yeah you're right. I'm trying to use Electron rn so I can convert it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the server always responds with index.html, regardless of the URL path.

You can use `path.normalize` with `URL.pathname`.

The code should be something like this:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const PORT=8080;

http.createServer((req, res) => {
  const url = new URL(req.url, 'http://localhost') // http://localhost is just dummy
  let filePath = url.pathname == '/' ? './index.html' : `./assets/${path.normalize(url.pathname.replace('/', '')).replace(/\.\.\//gi, '')}` // XSS Protection: limit all URL path in assets directory and index.html
  fs.readFile(filePath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.end('Not found');
    } else {
      res.writeHead(200);
      res.end(data);
    }
  })
}).listen(PORT);
```

When using this code, you should create a directory named `assets` and put all the css and js files(`canvas.js` and `style.css` for this code) inside. Don't put index.html and server code inside it.

Comment: hi, thanks for your answer! I actually read from one of the comments that I may not require all the server code to convert it into an exe. Thanks for your help!